# How to compare 2 commits inclusive using GitHub URL?

Tags: git, github, diff, git-commit

I have 2 consecutive commits, e.g., [fc07217](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/commit/fc07217d85e6dcec52878807d6bbd89a9d9156a5) and [cb7373b](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/commit/cb7373b46960e4bb1dee5758d6782a6fea19713b). I can view the changes made by the commit `fc07217` via https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/compare/cb7373b...fc07217. How can I obtain the changes brought in by **both** of these commits? I.e., the result of https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/compare/795ed8a...fc07217, but without the explicit mention of the `cb7373b`'s parent commit `795ed8a`.

It might be useful to check the commits between some commit and the repository initial commit `ec27d5d8` inclusive, because you can't specify the parent of the initial commit.

[Relevant doc](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/committing-changes-to-your-project/viewing-and-comparing-commits/comparing-commits#comparing-commits) doesn't mention this possibility.

Comment: You can use `^` after a commit to reference its direct parent. So [https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/compare/cb7373b^...fc07217](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/compare/cb7373b^...fc07217) should work. Alternatively `~1` is the same thing as `^`.

Comment: @JoachimSauer yes, it works when there is a parent commit, but it doesn't work for the initial commit case (`ec27d5d8`).

Comment: The initial commit has no parent (by definition), so it can't work. Since commits in git don't store "changes" (they always store a complete snapshot) the question of "what's the diff of the initial commit" is non-sensical in the git world. The closest you could get to that is printing the entire content of the initial commit. In other words: if you want a diff to the "empty git repo", then just look at the last commit in your range. The whole content is the diff.

Comment: @JoachimSauer in precise words, I need "what commits were made between `fc07217` and `ec27d5d8` inclusively and their contents" using GitHub UI, not the diff between `fc07217` and `ec27d5d8`.

Comment: I don't think you can get that from the GitHub UI. But GitHub UI and API questions are about GitHub, not about Git.

Comment: "diff with the initial commit inclusive" is simply : the content of the topmost commit, and consider that all the content has been added (`tree/<topmost>`). If you *really* insist on viewing it as a diff in github, you can create a phony commit with an empty tree, and compare `<empty>...<topmost>`

Comment: @LeGEC: Git repositories have an empty tree, so if you have a way to compare tree-to-tree with a GitHub URL (not sure if there is one, the commit-vs-commit one takes commits, but does it take tree object IDs?) you can use the [empty tree](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9765453/1256452).

Comment: @torek it can take commits, tags, branches and even forks, but I've already tried `4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904` and it doesn't work.

Comment: @LeGEC yeah, I think a dummy commit is the only way…